# How to get a more traditional-looking for protected constants

Tags: output-formatting

Is there any solution to make rule to export as a traditional form protected constants. Here is example which doesn't work.

```
aa = I0*I0;
rules11 = {I0 :> 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[
OverscriptBox[\(I\), \(^\)], \(0\), \(0, 2\)]\)};

  aa //. rules11 // TraditionalForm
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17633/5

Comment: Another closely related post that describes the techniques in detail is: [Simplistic Notation example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18441/245)

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16652/12